# know deployment target in index.js firebase functions

Tags: firebase, deployment

I have two deployment targets in my Cloud Functions. I use the command line to determine which project I deploy too. `firebase use myTestApp` or `firebase use myLiveApp`

Can I tell which target I am using in my index.js code?

I am hoping for something like this

```
// change baseURLs and other keys
if (Target == live) {
    const baseURL = 'myLiveApp';
    const stripekey= 'secreteLivekey';
} else {
    const baseURL = 'myTestApp';
    const stripekey= 'secreteTestkey';
};
```

currently I get around this by commenting out the test or live keys and this is very annoying and easy to make a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the necessary variables in each project's Functions config.

CLI:

```
firebase use <live_project>
firebase functions:config:set stripe.key="secreteLivekey"
firebase functions:config:set baseURL="myLiveApp"
firebase use <non_live_project>
firebase functions:config:set stripe.key="secreteTestkey"
firebase functions:config:set baseURL="myTestApp"
```

In code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
const baseURL = functions.config().baseURL
const stripekey = functions.config().stripe.key
```

EDIT:

Since your question technically was "Can you know your deployment target?", the answer is yes.

```
const config = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG)
const projectId = config.projectId
```